# Is allowed in islam to work as a bartender?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, work, adab

Is it allowed to work as a bartender or a steward in a bar that serves alchool?

I want to know whether it's haram or halal or makruh and what argument back this "fatwa".

Comment: I am not aware that there is a Fetwa regarding this specific situation but Hadith is very clear on this - so there is no need for a specific Fetwa... see my answer below...

Answer (score 7):

Working as bartender/steward means in the end that part of your work is serving/transporting/selling alcohol - people doing this are cursed according to this hadith:

> Al-Tirmidhi Hadith 2776        Narrated by Anas ibn Malik
>
> Allah's Messenger (saws) invoked the curse of Allah on ten people in
>   connection with wine:  the wine-presser, the one who has it pressed,
>   the one who drinks it, the one who conveys it, the one to whom it is
>   conveyed, the one who serves it, the one who sells it, the one who
>   benefits from the price paid for it, the one who buys it, and the one
>   for whom it is bought.

I am no Alim but: Yes, IMHO it is haraam to work as bartender/steward if alcohol is part of it.

Further reading you might find interesting:

- http://www.islam-qa.com/en/40651
- http://www.islamhelpline.com/node/5041
- http://etori.tripod.com/on-intoxicants.html
- http://authentichadiths.blogspot.de/2012/01/working-in-clubs-that-sell-alcohol.html

Comment: +1 for the reference from Tirmidhi. Even if the OP doesn't read the links, the hadeeth is plenty enough and clear.

Answer (score 1):

See the Verses from 90th Verse from 5th Lesson (Ma'idah 5:9 0)of Quran Shareef:
[image]

Whatever you are doing is not considered here, But the result that your action may reflecting are strictly prohibited by Islam. That is it may help someone to take alcohol. More than that the money or profit that you are payed from that bar/shop is also made\earned from haram. So it is not good to have a job in bar\ something like that.

Hope this helps. Include me in your Dua. :)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].